# Reading XML content of package.xml file from wsusscn2.cab

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to read the contents of package.xml file from the wsussncn2.cab that contains the list of Patches/Hotfixes from Microsoft to fperform a search for all available files for Windows 2008R2 and 2012 R2 product.
I extract the file from [`wsusscn2.cab`](http://download.windowsupdate.com/microsoftupdate/v6/wsusscan/wsusscn2.cab). The file `Package.xml` is quite big, but seems that I'm able to read with PowerShell. Other programs like editors use to fail.

From PowerShell I use use a code like this to perform some searches:

```
[xml]$xdoc = gc .\package.xml
$xdoc | Select-Xml "//OfflineSyncPackage"
```

or

```
$xdoc | Select-Xml "//Updates"
```

or any other category, It returns nothing.

But when I use:

```
$xdoc.SelectNodes("/*/*/*")
```

then I was able to get information from it, and also if I access like if it were an object:

```
$xdoc.OfflineSyncPackage.Updates.update.Categories.Category
```

Do you know why I can't use `Select-Xml` or why I should select for all with '*' in `SelectNodes()`?

How can I should perform the XML search for this file?

Answer (score 1):

The XML uses namespaces:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfflineSyncPackage MinimumClientVersion="5.8.0.2678"
    ProtocolVersion="1.0"
    PackageId="f27201b9-eca7-43ee-aed8-f7a2cddfec8b"
    SourceId="cc56dcba-9026-4399-8535-7a3c9bed7086"
    CreationDate="2016-10-10T22:40:27Z"
    PackageVersion="1.1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/msus/2004/02/OfflineSync">
  <Updates>
    ...
  </Updates>
</OfflineSyncPackage>
```

so you need a namespace manager for handling them, like this:

```bsh
[xml]$xdoc = gc .\package.xml

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xdoc.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$xdoc.SelectNodes('//ns:Updates', $nsm)
```

or like this:

```bsh
[xml]$xdoc = gc .\package.xml
$ns = @{ns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/msus/2004/02/OfflineSync'}

Select-Xml -Xml $xdoc -Namespace $ns -XPath '//ns:Updates'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is the first time for me that I'll have to use XML NameSpaces.